# Existe "inline functions" en JavaScript o react-native(componente) que paresca o sea igual a "inline functions" de Matlab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, matlab, react-hooks

```
f=inline("x^2+2*x+1");// en matlab 
f(3)// esto retornaria 16
```

En JavaScript o un componente que haga eso en react native?????

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente, lo más cercano sería una [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) que devuelva el resultado con [evil](http://www.zonavirus.com/articulos/eval-la-funcion-maligna-de-javascript.asp), perdón, [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval)

```js
let e = x => eval('x^2+2*x+1'); // ^ No es un operador válido
let f = x => eval('x*x+2*x+1');
let j = x => eval('Math.pow(x, 2)+2*x+1');
console.log(e(3));
console.log(f(3));
console.log(j(3));
```

Con esto enfrentarías 2 problemas:

1. Los operadores de Matlab no aplican igual en Javascript y, como referencia, el `^` no funciona para elevar a una potencia, aunque hay alternativas como [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/pow)
2. No es recomendable el uso de `eval()`, especialmente si las entradas provienen de usuarios

Por cierto, mientras buscaba información para responder, encontré que tampoco es recomendable usar funciones inline en Mathlab. [Referencia en inglés](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inline.html)

Comment: Gracias ... lo probaré ...